# Android getting Unexpected top-level exception

Tags: android, google-maps

For Android when ever I add google-maps-sdk-m4b (google maps api for work) to my project I am getting

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:282)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

From reading other post regarding similar issue seems to suggest that I need to exclude play-services library but I need the play-services library in order to get Google messaging services working for the app. according to the Google document

*When migrating your application to the Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work, you do not need to remove the Google Play services SDK from your project. However, you should remove any references to the com.google.android.gms.maps package*

These are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/androidnetworking.jar')
compile project(':facebook')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile project(':library_pulltorefresh')
compile(name:'google-maps-sdk-m4b', ext:'aar')
}
```

Not really sure why I am getting this error as I need to keep both of those packages. Can some one please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has occurred because the dex file format has a limit of 65535 methods, and you have exceeded it.

Read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) about building apps with too many methods, but the basic requirements are:

Enable multidex support in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` to reference `MultiDexApplication`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. I been tying to fix this for the last 8 hours and was crying in the corner when I saw this post. Thank you very much :D

Comment: Glad you got your issue sorted out :)

Answer (score -1):

Please change of dependencies as following :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':facebook') // if possible use gradle here
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile project(':library_pulltorefresh') // if possible use gradle here
compile(name:'google-maps-sdk-m4b', ext:'aar')
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried that. It still showing the same error. thanks tho

Comment: @ user767018 : Please try this -> dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}